# Annotate greenDao generated object

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I see that greenDao prefers not to use annotations for DAO and TO generation due to performance issues. However what if I still need to annotate for instance a TO for parser purposes? Is there any way to achieve that?

Example:

If we create a Customer entity with GreenDAO code generation, it will create the CustomerDAO and the Customer classes, right?

So, what if I`m consuming SOAP webservices, which returns a Customer object, and to facilitate parsing this Customer object I use an annotated kind of framework like simpleXML. Is there any  way to change the Customer class without loose every annotation when regenerating code with GreenDAO?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try using our fork at Path which adds supports for Annotations. (it also adds support for enum and serialization)
https://github.com/path/greenDAO
it is on my plate to send a pull request for it but not sure when I'll have time.

btw, our version is not well unit-tested as greenDAO but we've been using it on production for a while so should be stable enough.

To add annotations, you can check this sample code:
https://github.com/path/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoExampleGenerator/src/de/greenrobot/daogenerator/gentest/ExampleDaoGenerator.java#L42

btw, our fork creates two classes for each Entity object. An `EntityBase` which is abstract and includes all fields etc and an `Entity` which extends `EntityBase`. You should only edit `Entity`.

Comment: This way ok, but i don't get the use of the two classes for each entity. The concrete class does not have anything other than constructors. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: it lets us override setters and getters and also keeps our custom code away from the generated code (except the constructor). FYI, we never touch BaseEntity classes as they sit in a src-gen folder away from the rest of the source code.

Answer (score 9):

You can add annotations with greendao 2.0 like this

```
entity.addStringProperty("title").codeBeforeField("@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName( \"title\" )");
```

Comment: or `entity.addImport("com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName");
     entity.addLongProperty("mobile").codeBeforeField("@SerializedName( \"mobile\" )");` :)